# Access secret environment properties in IBM cloud deploy - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I'm having some problem with accessing my secret environments properties I've set in my build stage. In the build environment properties I got two secret fields called "w_username" and "w_password", however, I can not access these properties inside of my NodeJS runtime. I've tried with `process.env['w_username']` but it seems like it can't find it. How is it possible to access them?

Using NodeJS 6.x, npm 6.x with SDK for NodeJS on IBM cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the build environment properties in the next stage in the toolchain with their names like `w_username` and `w_password`.

> You can examine the environment properties for a pipeline job by
>   running the env command in the job's script.

You can also define your own environment properties. For example, you might define an API_KEY property that passes an API key that is used to access IBM Cloud resources by all scripts in the pipeline.

You can add the following types of properties:

- Text: A property key with a single-line value.
- Text Area: A property key with a multi-line value.
- Secure: A property key with a single-line value that is secured with AES-128 encryption. The value is displayed as asterisks.
- Properties: A file in the project's
  repository. This file can contain multiple properties. Each property
  must be on its own line. To separate key-value pairs, use the equals
  sign (=). Enclose all string values in quotation marks. For example,
  MY_STRING="SOME STRING VALUE".

For more information, refer [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/pipeline_about.html#environment_properties)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. But how am I suppose to access these properties in my node program? I understand that I can access them in the next stage in my toolchain, however the build stage is my last one and I want to access those properties inside my node application.